# SOLIDWORKS Save a drawing as PDF with property driven name

Tags: macos, solidworks

My goal is to write a macro witch does the following:
When opened drawing

1. Reads custom property of the drawing (in current case QDS_revision)
2. Reads custom property of referenced part / assembly (QDS_No)
3. Saves the drawing as PDF in a folder with name PDF in the same directory with name QDS_No + QDS_revision

This code does 1) and 3), but I can't read the info from 2). Any suggestions?
Runtime error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set
swCustPrpMgr = Nothing

```
Dim swApp As Object

Sub main()
Dim swApp           As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModel         As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim swDraw          As SldWorks.DrawingDoc
Dim swPart          As SldWorks.PartDoc

Dim swExportPDFData As SldWorks.ExportPdfData
Dim status          As Boolean
Dim errors          As Long, warnings As Long
Dim swCustPrpMgr    As SldWorks.CustomPropertyManager

Dim FullPath        As String
Dim Folder          As String
Dim NewFullPath     As String
Dim QDS_rev         As String
Dim QDS             As String


Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
Set swDraw = swModel

        ' Âçèìà àêòèâíàòà êîíôèãóðàöèÿ
        Dim swView                      As SldWorks.View
        Dim swBaseView                  As SldWorks.View
        Dim config                      As String
        
        Set swView = swDraw.GetFirstView
        Set swBaseView = swView.GetBaseView
        Set swView = swView.GetNextView
        config = swView.ReferencedConfiguration
        
        'Debug.Print "  " & config
        Set swCustPrpMgr = swModel.Extension.CustomPropertyManager(config)
        
        swCustPrpMgr.Get4 "QDS_No", False, "##", QDS   ' <=============Not either
        

Debug.Print QDS


'Save
status = swModel.Save3(swSaveAsOptions_e.swSaveAsOptions_Silent, errors, warnings)


If (swModel.GetType = swDocDRAWING) Then

    Set swCustPrpMgr = swModel.Extension.CustomPropertyManager("")
        swCustPrpMgr.Get4 "QDS_revision", False, "##", QDS_rev
        'swCustPrpMgr.Get4 "QDS_No", False, "##", QDS  ' <=============Not working either

    ' PathName of current model document
    FullPath = swModel.GetPathName

    ' get path name
    Folder = Left(FullPath, InStrRev(FullPath, "\"))
    Folder = Folder & "PDF" + "\"

    NewFullPath = Folder & QDS & QDS_rev & ".pdf"

    swModel.SaveAs3 NewFullPath, 0, 0

                        

End If

End Sub
```

I have tried different metods to gain the properties of the part / assembly, but non have worked

Answer (score -1):

Add a new variable

> **Dim val As String**

Then change

> swCustPrpMgr.Get4 "QDS_No", False, "##", QDS
>
> to
>
> swCustPrpMgr.Get4 "QDS_No", False, **val**, QDS

and

> swCustPrpMgr.Get4 "QDS_revision", False, "##", QDS_rev
>
> to
>
> swCustPrpMgr.Get4 "QDS_revision", False, **val**, QDS_rev

Check the macro I've posted here which saves the PDF file with the desired property name for reference https://www.linkedin.com/posts/gupta9665_solidworks-macro-solidworks-activity-7011944730934566912-xLQg

Comment: No, I won't follow the link if I have to expect that I will only find a macro without any explanation. Even with an explanation promised I won't follow the link, because the answer should be here, not there.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

The macro I've posted the link has a user form and it does the required work as stated by the OP.

I'm new to SO, so learning...